# Stop Spotify from finishing session due to lack of activity

Tags: spotify

I am a premium user, have my whole playlist downloaded to the phone and daily play it in offline mode. Either in offline and online mode after several songs or minutes all music stops, songs stop loading, the queue shows as empty and I have to return to the playlist view and click a new song for the session to restart.

Is there any way to bypass this timeout restriction?

Comment: You "*have to return*"?

Comment: It got cut. Editing.

Comment: I'm not sure why is this happening. I haven't used Spotify on mobile in a while but nothing like this happened to me. 4+ hour long playlists played without any problems.